# Item coulours in ncurses menu

Tags: ncurses

Does anyone know whether it is possible to make a menu in ncurses show different items with different colours? As far as I found out, it is only possible to change its foreground and background colours. If not possible, is there any other 3rdparty menu implementation that allows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu library does not provide a way to set the colors of individual menu items.
I'm afraid you will need to implement your own menu or modify the menu library that comes with ncurses.

Comment: Yes, I alos think so. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [S-lang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/doc/html/cref-4.html#ss4.10) library provides good color options; you can see how it is used in the [`mutt` email client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%28e-mail_client%29).

Comment: Unfortunately,  I should keep the application using Ncurses and I can't move it to s-lang.

Comment: Hrm, [`irssi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irssi) appears to be linked against `ncurses` on my system -- perhaps ncurses _is_ flexible enough to specify more than just the two colors?